# Rename folder in SD card

Tags: android, directory, rename

This must be, supposedly, a very simple task, but I've been around it for some time without successes...

In my app I create a folder in the SD card, where I store temporary jpg files. Since I don't want my app to show those temp files when browsing the phone for images, I was trying to make that folder hidden. So, right after creation the dir, I tried to rename it, like this:

```
String tmppath="/sdcard/myapp/tmp";
try
{
//this creates a directory named TMP -->OK!
 File f=new File(tmppath); 
  if(!f.isDirectory())  
   f.mkdirs();  

//this was supposed to rename the directory to .TMP, but isn't working...

Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv "+tmppath +" /sdcard/myapp/.tmp/");
process.waitFor();
}
catch(SecurityException e)
{
}
catch(IOException e)
{
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) 
{
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
File file = new File("your old file name");
File file2 = new File("your new file name");
boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
final File F=new File("youroldpath");  
String newname="newname";  
File newfile=new File(F.getParent(),newname);  
F.renameTo(newfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [renameTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method in File? [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_renameto.htm) is an example of renaming a file or folder.

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.File;

public class FileDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      File f = null;
      File f1 = null;
      boolean bool = false;

      try{      
         // create new File objects
         f = new File("C:/test.txt");
         f1 = new File("C:/testABC.txt");

         // rename file
         bool = f.renameTo(f1);

         // print
         System.out.print("File renamed? "+bool);

      }catch(Exception e){
         // if any error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Juan Thanks for pointing this out, I have updated the example url